# unable to dismiss Progress dialog using dismiss method in android

Tags: android, kotlin, progressdialog

```
class CShowProgress(context: Context) {
    var s_m_oCShowProgress: CShowProgress? = null
    lateinit var m_Dialog: Dialog
    private var m_ProgressBar: ProgressBar? = null
    private var progressText: TextView? = null

    fun getInstance(): CShowProgress {
        if (s_m_oCShowProgress == null) {
            s_m_oCShowProgress = CShowProgress(context!!)
        }
        return s_m_oCShowProgress as CShowProgress
    }

    fun show(m_Context: Context, message: String) {
        m_Dialog = Dialog(m_Context)
        m_Dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        m_Dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_bar)
        m_ProgressBar = m_Dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressBar_cyclic)
        m_ProgressBar!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        m_ProgressBar!!.isIndeterminate = true
        m_Dialog.setCancelable(false)
        m_Dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        m_Dialog.show()
    }

    fun dismiss(m_Context: Context) {
        m_Dialog = Dialog(m_Context)
        m_Dialog.dismiss()
    }
}
```

This is my singlton class for custom Progress dialog for show dialog we have show method and for dismiss we have dismiss method  i am calling this class

```
    CShowProgress(this).getInstance().show(this, "Please wait..")
     and for dismiss i am calling 

    CShowProgress(this).getInstance().dismiss(this)
```

using show i am able to show Progress dialog but using dimiss i am not able to dismiss can any one please tell me what i am doing wrong i am using kotlin language .

Answer (score 1):

When you call your dismiss fun you create a new unshown dialog and trying to dismiss it.

Here i modified your dismiss func. I think this'll help you.g

```
fun dismiss() {
    if(m_Dialog.isShowing){
        m_Dialog.dismiss()
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Oh sorry i did not check your singleton pattern. When you call `CShowProgress(this)` you create a new instance of your class so you cannot dismiss previous ones dialogs.

You can create a `Singleton` like below:

```
companion object {
    lateinit var instance: CShowProgress
        private set
}
```

And init like this:

```
instance = CShowProgress(context)
```

And use show dialog like this:

```
CShowProgress.instance.show(context,message)
```

And dimiss it like this:

```
CShowProgress.instance.dismiss()
```

But i think if you refactor code like this, you'll still face another issue i explained below.

Also when you show a new dialog you loose reference to your old dialog so you cannot dismiss it. Basicly you're creating n dialog but only hold reference to your last created dialog. So you cannot dismiss previous ones. So if you go on like this you can dismiss your previous dialog if exists before showing a new one. But this pattern is hard to manage multiple alert dialogs so i suggest you to change it.

```
fun show(m_Context: Context, message: String) {
        if(m_Dialog.isShowing){
            m_Dialog.dismiss()
        }
        m_Dialog = Dialog(m_Context)
        m_Dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        m_Dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_bar)
        m_ProgressBar = m_Dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressBar_cyclic)
        m_ProgressBar!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        m_ProgressBar!!.isIndeterminate = true
        m_Dialog.setCancelable(false)
        m_Dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        m_Dialog.show()
    }
```

Finally passing `Activity` `context` to a singleton object and do not clear when activity `onDestroy` will cause memory leaks.

Comment: Ok wait let me try this

Comment: not working can u please tell me how to call show and dismiss method in actvity @savepopulation

Comment: can u please give me Complete class  with Singlton in @savepopulation i am not able to change it coz i am new in kotlin

Comment: No need for the null check btw. m_Dialog is already defined as a non-null reference

Comment: @DevenDcostra i think for showing / dismissing you should not use singleton pattern. You can check kotlin extensions for these kind of tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
class CShowProgress(context: Context) {
     var s_m_oCShowProgress: CShowProgress? = null
     lateinit var m_Dialog: Dialog
     private var m_ProgressBar: ProgressBar? = null
     private var progressText: TextView? = null

fun getInstance(): CShowProgress {
    if (s_m_oCShowProgress == null) {
        s_m_oCShowProgress = CShowProgress(context!!)
    }
    return s_m_oCShowProgress as CShowProgress
}

fun show(m_Context: Context, message: String) {
    m_Dialog = Dialog(m_Context)
    m_Dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    m_Dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_bar)
    m_ProgressBar = m_Dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressBar_cyclic)
    m_ProgressBar!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    m_ProgressBar!!.isIndeterminate = true
    m_Dialog.setCancelable(false)
    m_Dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
    m_Dialog.show()
}

fun dismiss() {
   //no need to re initialise dialog only check for if the dialog is showing
    if(m_Dialog.isShowing){
       m_Dialog.dismiss()
    }
}
}
```

in your activity create a object for the class and use show and dismiss methods just like this

```
 val dialoge:CShowProgress = CShowProgress(this)//create object for the class

    dialoge.show(this,"Your message")//for showing the dialog

    dialoge.dismiss()//to dismiss the dialog
```

Comment: wait let me try this then i will tell its working or not

Comment: not working can u please tell me how to call show and dismiss method in actvity @Nikhil Jadhav